# Does the Facebook app have a unique access_token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Does the generated access_token for the app on page https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
always remain unique or can it be changed by Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, but generally the access_token changes everything a new one is requested. In some cases, the same token may be returned but the expiry time will be updated. The tokens are unique to a user and app.

Facebook also says:

> Expect that the size of all types of access tokens will change over
>   time as Facebook makes changes to what is stored in them and how they
>   are encoded. You can expect that they will grow and shrink over time.
>   Please use a variable length data type without a specific maximum size
>   to store access tokens.